# Altering my MySQL query to implement sorting

Tags: mysql

I currently implement the following query to obtain all posts in the database that have specific interest tags in common with the user and sort these via the time posted. The query I have at the moment works perfect. However, I am planning a sorting tool for users to sort posts by score (calculated by likes or dislikes).

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM posts AS p
  INNER JOIN post_tag AS posttag ON p.post_id = posttag.post_id
  INNER JOIN profile_tag AS profiletag ON posttag.tag_id = profiletag.tag_id
  INNER JOIN profile AS profile ON profile.profile_id = profiletag.profile_id
WHERE     profile.username = 'username'
ORDER BY time_posted DESC
```

Now, the likes are held in a table "Likes" with the columns:

```
post_id | score
```

So when a user scores a post, the `post_id` and the `score` is added to this table and therefore not every post will have a score. I am stuck on what steps to get to implement the ability to sort the posts by the score.

A post with no score would be 0.

Edit:

An example:

```
post_id|score
    1     1
    1     1 
    2     1
```

So the post 1 has a total of 2 likes, and post has 1, so it would be sorted according to the sum of each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just INNER JOIN the Likes table without adding anything to the SELECT statement.  Then, you could sort by it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM posts AS p
  INNER JOIN post_tag AS posttag ON p.post_id = posttag.post_id
  INNER JOIN profile_tag AS profiletag ON posttag.tag_id = profiletag.tag_id
  INNER JOIN profile AS profile ON profile.profile_id = profiletag.profile_id
  INNER JOIN Likes AS l ON l.post_id = p.post_id
WHERE     profile.username = 'username'
ORDER BY l.score, time_posted DESC
```

Comment: Then try sorting by the count(score)

Comment: I tried this however it only seems to show the result of one post? This is what I changed: `ORDER BY count(l.score) DESC`

Comment: Yikes... sorry about that.  Don't know what I was thinking.  Try Sum() instead maybe?

Comment: no luck! The same thing happens where only one result is returned. It seems to only return the item with the highest score.

Comment: Ok... Include sum(score) in your SELECT statement, then GROUP BY post_id.

Comment: That joins the correct tables together now however the sum calculated is incorrect EDIT: after editing the query slightly it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I know this is answered but is there any way the query can still show posts that have a score of 0?

Comment: Instead of INNER JOIN Likes, use: LEFT OUTER JOIN Likes